# Как создать форму обратной связи через API bitrix?

Tags: php, битрикс, форма

Помогите пожалуйста создать форму обратной связи на 3 инпута,один из них type=file. Создать необходимо через битрикс API. Использование стандартных компонентов запрещено. Какой должен быть алгоритм построения? сам код?
С алгоритмом мне вроде понятно:

1. Мне необходимо разместить инпуты.
2. Взять их ИД.
3. В этих ИД(инпутах) взять значение атрибута value и передать его в инфоблок или отправить на почту.
   А вот с кодом не могу разобраться, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Почему стандартные компоненты запрещены?

Comment: @nazarpunk Это как тестовое задание. Я сделал все на стандартных компонентах, но в задании было указанно сделать, через API. Попросили переделать.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно перехватывать отправку формы JS скриптом и отправлять с помощью `BX.ajax.runComponentAction` на выполнение, реализованное в class.php или ajax.php компонента.

Вот примеры к учебному курсу [Контроллеры](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=03750&LESSON_PATH=3913.3516.5062.3750).

Если имелось в виду rest api инфоблоков, дополню/поправлю ответ.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).